# Why is comma used here?

Tags: punctuation

I cannot find any reason to put a comma after "issues."

Please note that "Lease" is a name.

[image: ACT 71E]

Comment: It is because the main sentence is "Lease presented complex issues in a confident, straightforward manner." Since a new clause was introduced between "issues" and "in" ("such as interest rates"), a comma after "issues" and one before "in" are needed.

Comment: I have four more questions, but I can only ask one question in every 40 minutes. What should I do?

Comment: You will have to wait, as you can only ask one question per post, unless they are part of the same bigger issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma after issues is paired with the comma after rates.  The phrase "such as interest rates" is a [parenthetical phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthesis_(rhetoric)), and English often uses a pair of commas or dashes around them.

Without the parenthetical phrase:

> A shrewd speaker, Lease presented complex issues in a confident, straightforward, manner...

The parenthetical phrase "such as interest rates" gives an example of what the author means by "complex issues".

You could argue in this case that the parenthetical phrase is short enough that it doesn't need commas, but it's a matter of style, not a hard rule.

Comment: I would remove the comma after straightforward. It is only there as part of the question to choose the right combination of commas, and the right combination does not include that one.